# How to extract digits from string and return the last 3 or less using regex

Tags: python, regex

Consider the string `s`

```
s = 'hello1 my45-fr1@nd5'
```

I want to strip out the last 3 digits `'515'`.  I know I can do

```
import re

re.sub(r'\D', '', s)[-3:]

'515'
```

However, I need a single regex substitution that performs the same task.

Comment: so it has to be a pure regex solution, no array indexing?

Comment: You want to _extract_ them?

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 yes.  I want to pass this through another piece of api and it needs to be regex only.

Comment: can you use string reversal?

Comment: Can we assume that there are at least 3 digits?

Comment: If you're using pandas, why not just `.str[-3:]`?

Comment: No string manipulation other than through regex.  The question is me trying to figure out how to perform such a task via regex.

Comment: Yes, we can assume at least 3 digits.

Comment: Just confirming, is two sub calls okay?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ no.  I wanted just one.

Comment: XYproblem.jpeg.

Comment: Also, feedback on why you would downvote this question would be appreciated.  I couldn't find an answer after searching.  This is a non-trivial question.

Comment: @Ryan, This is not an XY problem.  I manufactured this problem to target precisely what I wanted to know.  That is the point MCVE.  Both answers below seemed to have understood what I've asked.

Comment: @piRSquared: Oh, I *understand* what you asked (and the question is easy), but you should explain why you want to do it anyway, even if that’s just “because I’m curious” (but we know that’s not the case because you commented “I want to pass this through another piece of api”). Because it is an XY problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I do feel that the python tag was a bit misleading if all you want is a POSIX regular expression

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this `re.sub` using a lookahead:

```
>>> s = 'hello1 my45-fr1@nd5'
>>> print re.sub(r'\D+|\d(?=(?:\D*\d){3,}\D*$)', '', s)
515
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZaTffV/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\D+                    # match 1 or more non-digits
|                      # OR
\d                     # match a digit
(?=(?:\D*\d){3,}\D*$)  # that is followed by 3 or more digits in the string
```

Positive Lookahead `(?=(?:\D*\d){3,}\D*$)` asserts that we have at least 3 digits ahead of us from current position.

Comment: Brilliant, that's the logic I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: @anubhava   This is a brilliant answer but I'm having trouble understanding one portion. I ran `re.findall(r'\D+|\d(?=(?:\D*\d){3,}\D*$)', s)` and the result I got was `['hello', '1', ' my', '4', '-fr', '@nd', 'dd']`. I don't understand how we get `-fr`, `@and`,  and `dd` in our result set as the positive lookahead forces us to have 3 or instances of` (\D*\d)` right?   By the time our cursor gets to `-fr` we only have two digits left.

Answer (score 5):

Using a bit of brute force and capturing groups, you can use

```
.*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*(\d)\D*$
```

and replace it with

```
\1\2\3
```

See https://regex101.com/r/h2bFeV/2